# Alternative to discontinued Facebook Connect

Tags: sync, facebook, people

Microsoft recently sent out a bulletin that mentions the discontinuation of Facebook Connect integration with Windows Phone.

In my opinion, one of the best features of Windows Phone is the ability to integrate your social networks with Outlook and have Outlook be your one stop shop for all your "People".

[The bulletin is available to read here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Facebook-Connect-is-no-longer-available-f31c8107-7b5a-4e3d-8a22-e506dacb6db6?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB#BKMK_outlook.com).

The part that is particularly dissapointing:

> ### **Outlook.com Contacts**
>
> If you’re a new user, you won’t be able to connect your Facebook contacts to your Outlook.com account.
>
> **If you’ve previously connected your Facebook account to Outlook.com, your Facebook contacts will no longer be updated with information from Facebook.**

Until now, I liked that my Outlook.com People section had all my contacts from all my services. A lot of these contacts came from Facebook.

Is there a workaround to be able to continue to seamlessly sync by Facebook contacts to Outlook.com?

Comment: Have you got the Facebook app installed?

Comment: Yes, I have it...

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be any way to do it, due to API changes. More information [here](http://www.neowin.net/news/facebook-connect-is-no-longer-supported-on-windows-windows-phone-and-other-microsoft-services).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Facebook app installed and are running Windows Phone 8.1, then [Facebook contacts will continue to show on your phone](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Facebook-Connect-is-no-longer-available-f31c8107-7b5a-4e3d-8a22-e506dacb6db6?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#BKMK_peopleHub).