# Anyway to delete facebook contact info from my Nokia Lumia 520

Tags: lumia-520, facebook

I blocked someone on Facebook and since my Facebook is connected with my phone all the contact info from people show up in my phone but I want to delete this one persons info but it won't let me use the delete button

Answer (score 1):

If you have Facebook contacts showing up in your Windows Phone People app, it is because you have connected your Facebook account to your Microsoft account.

**Go in to the `Settings` app and then `email+accounts`. Long tap on `Facebook` and hit sync. This *should* sync with the cloud and get rid of the contact from the `People` app.**

If the above step doesn't reflect the contact's blocked status, read on. Facebook has changed the way it shares data with other companies and as such, if you were to link your Facebook account to your Windows Phone today, your Facebook contacts would NOT get added to the People app. [You can read more about this here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/9789/alternative-to-discontinued-facebook-connect).

Hence, as an alternative, you could disconnect Facebook from your phone altogether which will take away all Facebook contacts (including obviously the blocked contact). The only reason I am even suggesting this is because, over time, your new Facebook contacts will not get added to Windows Phone and hence things will be out of sync anyway.